# How to find the Author of a Font?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm working on a Android app project where i use **Malayalam fonts** (ML-TT-Revathi, ML-TT-Karthika, ML-TT-Ayilyam) and i need to know whether i need a license to use those fonts. All the fonts i use were found free on the web but each one is customized and have glyphs missing or represented by different unicode symbols. I need to get to the author of these fonts for the authentic version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the copyright details aren't shown in the Font previewer...

[image: Font preview for ML-TTRevathi]

then you may be able to find it using the File Properties themselves (right-click in Explorer and choose Properties).

[image: File Properties for ML-TTRevathi]

Unfortunately (at least in Windows 7) the properties aren't selectable. For this version of the font I found, the copyright data is

> COPYRIGHT (c) 1992-95, C-DAC, PUNE, INDIA.ISFOC-MALAYALAM-TTREVATHI-NORMAL

and I guess that [C-DAC](http://cdac.in/) are the people to ask.

If there are no Windows properties either, you could try opening the font file in Notepad to see if there are recognisable strings included in the data. Don't save it if you do this!

Comment: It is C-DAC. Thanks a lot, especially for the screenshots. They made it easy for me to understand. Let me see if I can get a license.